# Как повернуть объект в pgzero?

Tags: python

Мне нужна команда, которая может задать поворот объекту.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть же документация по [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#rotation). Если я правильно понял, то нужно установить `angle` в градусах:

```
asteroid = Actor('asteroid', center=(300, 300))

def update():
    asteroid.angle += 1
```

Либо задать направление на позицию другого объекта:

```
ship = Actor('ship')

def on_mouse_move(pos):
    ship.angle = ship.angle_to(pos)
```

Направление отсчитывается от направления вправо, против часовой стрелки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]